# sort(key=function) not working but sorted(iterable,key=function) is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I wanted to sort a list based on the index of the first occurrence of an element.

Example:

```
l=[3,2,1,2,3,1,4]
output=[3,3,2,2,1,1,4]
```

I tried the following code.

```
def sortfunc(idx:int):
    return l.index(idx)
print(sorted(l,key=sortfunc))
```

It working good but when I tried `l.sort(key=sortfunc)` Its raising `ValueError`.

```
>>> l=[3,2,1,2,3,1,4]
>>> l.sort(key=sortfunc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
    l.sort(key=sortfunc)
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 2, in sortfunc
    return l.index(idx)
ValueError: 3 is not in list
>>>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `l.sort()` modifies the list in place. While it's running, it may have to remove elements from the list temporarily.

Comment: Try `print(l)` inside `sortfunc`. When you call from `l.sort()` it is empty...

Comment: This might be because `sorted` operates on a copy of the original list `l`, and `l.sort` operates on the original list itself. Instead, you can create a copy of `l`, then tell the key function to get the index from the copy.